# why is my flutter validator from TextFormField not working properly?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-textformfield

I was working on my signup page, there is a form to fill. It includes first name, last name, phone number, email and password. i want to make an error massage whenever the form was filled incorrectly. everything works fine execpt the email. whenever i click my button to check, it has to be clicked 2 times in order for the massage to show. i want to get rid of this problem.

here's my code of the email field :

```
Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 24,
                      right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 24,
                      top: 12,
                      bottom: 12),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    //cek data field nya kosong
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Color(0xff303030)),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    onSaved: (input) => requestModel!.email = input,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Tolong Masukkan Email';
                      }
                      if (!RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-z]")
                          .hasMatch(value)) {
                        return 'Please Enter valid Email';
                      }
                      if (value.isNotEmpty &&
                          error ==
                              "Email Telah Terdaftar. Mohon Masukkan Email Lain!") {
                        return 'Email sudah terdaftar';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },

                    controller: emailController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                      hintText: 'Email Anda',
                      hintStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Color(0xff303030), fontSize: 12),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24),
                      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                          color: Color(0xffc0c0c0),
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                          color: Color(0xffc0c0c0),
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                          const Radius.circular(5.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

and here's my button :

```
Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 24.0, bottom: 5.0, left: 60.0, right: 60.0),
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      minWidth: 240.0,
                      color: Color(0xff0d579a),
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (validateAndSave()) {
                          SignUpAPIService apiService = new SignUpAPIService();
                          apiService.signUp(requestModel!).then((value) async {
                            if (value.status!.isNotEmpty) {
                              print(value.toString());
                              final snackbar = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                  .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                content: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.check_circle_sharp,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      size: 28,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      height: 32,
                                      width: 240,
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, top: 8),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Link sudah dikirimkan ke email Anda. Harap cek folder Spam atau Junk juga",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            color: Color(0xffffffff)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                                backgroundColor:
                                    Color(0xffcc0d579a).withOpacity(1),
                              ));
                            } else if (value.error!.isNotEmpty) {
                              print(value.error![0]);
                              setState(() {
                                error = value.error![0];
                              });
                            }
                          });
                          print(requestModel!.toJson());
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "Daftar",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                      ),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
                    )),
```

this is my first time encountering this problem and also i am a beginner in flutter. i don't  have enough knowledge to figure out this problem.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this method do: `validateAndSave()` ? Does it suppress the first click but allows the second click to go through?

Comment: that method is just to check if the form has error or not and to save the form. it returns bool

Comment: Could you show the method, please?

Comment: `bool validateAndSave() {
    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (form!.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }` sorry this is my first time using this website

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind to use `if (value == null || value.isEmpty)` instead of `if (value!.isEmpty)`. But I am not sure that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a diff approach, I'll change TextFormField to TextField and assign each a controller and create seperate private Boolean value for each field.

In the initState() func, add a listener to each controller with change in text-input to be sent to a validator function which changes the bool value for the field.

At the end you could just check if all the bool values are true, else show a Toast message.

```
final TextFieldController _phoneController;
final TextFieldController _mailController;
final TextFieldController _passwordController;

final bool _phoneVerified = false;
final bool _mailVerified = false;
final bool _passwordVerified = false;

void initState(){
 _phoneController = TextFieldController();
 _mailController = TextFieldController();
 _passwordController = TextFieldController();

 _phoneController.addListener(value){
  phoneValidator(value);
}
_mailController.addListener(value){
  mailValidator(value);
}
_passwordController.addListener(value){
  passwordValidator(value);
}
super.initState;
}

void dispose(){
 _phoneController.dispose;
 _mailController.dispose;
 _passwordController.dispose;
 super.dispose;
}

void phoneValidator(value) {
 ///validation here and change value of bool using setState
}

void emailValidator(value) {
 ///validation here and change value of bool using setState
}

void passwordValidator(value) {
 ///validation here and change value of bool using setState
}
```

at the end, while you take the submission, just check if all bool values are true, else raise a message.

Comment: can i just do this for the email ??

Comment: Yes. Change email 's TextFormField to TextField and follow the above process only for email, i.e _emailVerified bool, _emailController and emailValidator function